# How to use Google Analytics code with Angularjs

Tags: google-analytics

I have included **GA tracking code** in **head** tag of **index.html** of my **AngularJs** Application.But **Google Tag manager** says **"Missing closing script tag"**..Can anyone help me how to solve this issue and use Google Analytics in my Angularjs App..

Comment: Can't really help without seeing your code. Did you follow the message and check if you did leave out the closing script tag??

Comment: In my index.html of AngularJs Application I included the following code:

<script>
 (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
  i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
  i[r] = i[r] || function() {
   (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
  }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
  a = s.createElement(o),
   m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
  a.async = 1;
  a.src = g;
  m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
 })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

 ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX', 'auto');
 ga('send', 'pageview');
 </script>

Comment: @nyuen .. I am stuck now..Can you just guide me how to include GA Analytics in My AngularJS Application..

Comment: I'm not sure how to help. I think you should post the code that's on your site and screenshots of the error message. Without actually going to your site, it's harder to tell.